# Defadvice for C-k in emacs for js-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, paredit

I want to use the <kbd>C-k</kbd> to kill a block or kill the rest of current line in js-mode.

After I search google for a while, I think `defadvice` will be the answer but I am not familiar with elisp. So I hope somebody can help me write it :)

The function I mentioned is something like `paredit-mode` but I don't want to enable `paredit-mode` in `js-mode` as my requirements will be much simpler. When I am writing js, sometimes I want to kill the follow block like:

```
function test() {
    if () {
    } else {
    }
}
```

If the cursor is now between `function` and `test`, then I use <kbd>C-k</kbd> I can kill the whole block

```
        test() {
    if () {
    } else {
    }
}
```

with the only word `function` left. Here 'block' simply means something between '{}'.

If current line is not followed by a block, <kbd>C-k</kbd> should behave as its origin behavior, which should be `(kill-line &optional ARG)`, kill the rest of line by default.

If you are familiar with `paredit-mode`, you will find it just a very simple version of it!

I hope you can understand what I mean since my English is broken. Any help will be greatly appreciated !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd recommend against using an advice for that, since you can just rebind `C-k` in `js-mode-map` instead.  E.g.

```
(defun my-kill-line-or-block (&optional arg)
  "Kill line or whole block if line ends with a block opener."
  (interactive "P")
  (if (looking-at ".*\\({[^{}\n]*$\\)")
      (kill-region (point)
                   (progn (goto-char (match-beginning 1))
                          (forward-sexp 1)
                          (point)))
    (kill-line arg)))

(define-key js-mode-map [?\C-k] 'my-kill-line-or-block)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(defadvice kill-visual-line (around cus-kill activate)
  (unless (let ((mark-point (point)))
            (if (search-forward "{" (line-end-position) t)
                (kill-region mark-point (scan-sexps (- (point) 1) 1))))
    ad-do-it))
```

In my case, **C-k** is bind to *kill-visual-line*. If you make sure that **C-k** is bind to *kill-line*(check it using **C-h k C-k**), then change *kill-visual-line* to *kill-line* in that function.

PS: The function is not fully tested. If the {} is not balanced an warning is signaled by scan-sexps. You can just ignore it.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I'm going to try this.

Comment: I recommend you avoid using `1` to stand for the "first position in the buffer" since that is not always the case.  Better use `point-min`.

Comment: @Stefan Thanks, I do not understand "first position in the buffer"  clearly...  Should I change (- (point) 1) to (- (point) (point-min)) ?

Comment: @louxiu: forget it, I was confused, sorry.